# Processing a large dataset using BASH scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a large filtered dataset on Wikipedia webpage accesses for an entire month. Day views of each article are stored '\t' separated. It has approximately 3000 entries of the following type:

For every article that has page-views over 100,000, print the following line as output (\t is the tab character):

```
10   ABC    20141101:1    20141102:2    20141103:0    20141104:0   
20141105:1    20141106:0    20141107:0    20141108:0    20141109:0   
20141110:6    20141111:0    20141112:0    20141113:0    20141114:0  
20141115:0    20141116:0    20141117:0    20141118:0    20141119:0   
20141120:0    20141121:0    20141122:0    20141123:0    20141124:0   
20141125:0    20141126:0    20141127:0    20141128:0    20141129:0   
20141130:0
```

> Where 20141130: means 30th Nov 2014:.

I need to compute the following queries on this dataset:

1. For how many days over the month was the page titled "XXX" more popular than the page titled "YYY"?
2. Rank in descending order the articles (read from a another file) based on their single day maximum Wiki pageviews. Print articles separated by a comma. I have written the code to read the articles from another file

   ```
   while read line
   do
       movie=$line
   echo "$movie,"; done < ArticleFileName
   ```
3. On which date did article "ZZZ" have the most number of page views? Print answer in yyyymmdd format.

I have tried many times but in vain.
Can anyone help?

Comment: consider editing your question to include sample output for each required output. Really, this should be 3 separate questions. How about if we help with the hardest problem, and then you wrestle some more with the easier ones and post followup questions as needed. Good luck.

Comment: Also, is your data really as shown? It will be easier to process if each element is one-per-line. Good luck.